# MySQL "file-per-table", database not selected Error

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a small self- contained C# project with a MySQL database on a Win10 minicomputer. Although small and simple, a constant up-to-date backup of at least one table of the database is necessary.  To add a replication server is not really feasible as the users want it totally easy to handle. So I thought a “file-per-table” on an outside directory (e.g. on a USB-stick on this minicomputer) could be the solution.

According to the MySQL 5.7 reference manual showing:

> mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/alternative/directory';

I tried this:

> mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/F/’;

I get:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

May be there is a total misunderstanding when I think that I can create one table of my database on a USB-stick (drive “F”) to hold a duplicate of the important table inside the database.

And I thought that calling the database (mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *******) already selects this one database I mean. But of course I could have more databases under the same user and password….

So if I am not totally wrong, how do I have to select the database?

Thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing because some people use the word "database" to mean the instance of MySQL you log into. But others use the word "database" mean a schema, which is like a folder in which you can create tables. You cannot create a table unless you do it inside a schema.

In MySQL, the keywords `DATABASE` and `SCHEMA` are interchangeable.

You should review the [MySQL tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tutorial.html), especially [Creating and Using a Database](http://%20https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-use.html).

That said, I think your plan to put a table on a USB stick drive is not going to work anyway. The file-per-table InnoDB tablespaces are not a backup. You can't just copy that file and get the data within it, and later restore the copy to another MySQL instance. The reason is that the file doesn't contain all the data. As you modify data, the changes go through different locations in RAM and in the central tablespace before they are eventually integrated into the file-per-table file. This can happen long after your application commits changes to MySQL. The changes are safe, they just aren't stored in the file-per-table file until some time later.

If you store a table on USB stick drive, and you yank it from the computer before it's fully in sync with recent changes, **you will corrupt your database.**

Another problem is that USB stick drives are many times slower than the computer's main hard disk. If you try to store part of the database on a USB stick drive, it will compromise the performance of your application. You won't like the result.

If you need to run backups frequently, you should use the backup tool provided, which is [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). You can back up an InnoDB table without locking it if you use the right option:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction mydatabase mytable > mytable.sql
```

The `--single-transaction` ensures a consistent read of the table(s) without locking it (as long as the table uses the InnoDB engine). It does this by using a transaction.

---

Re your comment:

You can run `mysqldump` pretty frequently. But it's still be something you must run. There are various scheduler tools for every operating system (for example, Windows 10 has the [Task Scheduler](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-task-scheduler-gives-power/)).

But if you have to account for hard drive failure, you need to have some separate storage. For example, you could put the output of the mysqldump onto a USB drive. Or you could upload the dump file to cloud storage.

I strongly recommend you do NOT configure any of your MySQL tablespaces to reside on removable storage. I wrote above that it will cause poor performance, and a high risk of corrupting your database. I don't know how to be any clearer that this is a BAD thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation! I thought that the dump has to be done manually from time to time to have a backup. But it sounds as if it can be automated and I hope it can be saved to an external drive. (in case the SSD on the computer breaks the schema can be restored from the external drive). 
But just to get it right: could I have a schema on the USB drive separately, while MySQL is only installed on the SSD of course? For the app it would not be a problem timewise to feed both schemas. The writes are at a minimum interval of about 20 sec…

Comment: Ok, it stores the dump-file to the directory you are in. So I type this to get the dumpfile on the USB-stick (F). PS C:\ > cd F:\ PS F:\> mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction db_mydb tab_mytab > mytab.sql; Enter password: ******* PS F:\> ... I will have to check then how to do this programatically from the app.